# MariaDB help_topic.* files

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have noticed that MariaDB (10) creates a stack of files bearing the name `help_topic.*` in `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/performance_schema`.  What purpose, if any do these files serve?  I ask because I am using MariaDB in a Docker container and want to try to trim all the fat.  If they are used to deliver help in any form I might be able to dispense with them.

Comment: I've never seen them in performance_schema and found no reference to them being in that location in the MariaDB docs. They are normally in the `{datadir}/mysql` directory itself. What are the extensions?

Comment: I got that slightly wrong. They are in fact under `/var/lib/mysql/mysql`. They are called `help_category|keword|relation|topic.MYD|MYI|FRM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those tables provide the content used by the `HELP` statement.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-side-help-support.html

Since they are MyISAM tables, you could try simply stopping the server, moving the files elsewhere (so the server can't see them), then starting it back up, and checking the logs for warnings or errors.  Additionally, you may want to try using the `HELP` command to be sure this doesn't cause any kind of internal panic if they are missing.  It shouldn't, of course, but you may want to verify.

Testing this on MySQL Server 5.6.14, there were no ill effects.  Using the `HELP` command just returns an error.

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.help_topic' doesn't exist.
```

Nothing was written in the error log, either on startup or coinciding with the client error, above.

You should be okay without them.

Comment: Thanks,  And - not for the first  time - could the person who silently voted to close my question come back and explain why. The question was badly phrased, not researched, not relevant....?

Comment: Not all votes to close reflect a negative view of the question.  That seems true in this case -- the close voter apparently thought your question would have been a better fit on http://serverfault.com since http://stackoverflow.com is targeted toward "programming."  I think it might also have been a good fit for http://dba.stackexchange.com ("a question and answer site for database professionals"), which you might want to check out, if you haven't already.